# Can't disable key in linux

Tags: linux, xorg

I am running xorg. I want to disabling my pagedown key. I determined the keycode:

```
$ sudo showkey
keycode 109 press
keycode 109 release
```

and attempted to disable by running:

```
$ sudo xmodmap -e 'keycode 109='
```

and

```
$ sudo xmodmap -e 'keycode 109=NoSymbol'
```

Neither of those variations disabled the key. Suggestions?

Comment: why is the title not `how to disable key in linux?`

Comment: Remove key cap, or put rubber under key cap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `xmodmap` without `sudo` in order to set it for your current user's X session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).